Unable to acquire a token in IAuthDelgate of the microsoft information protection sdk
I am generating an Excel file to which I have to add a sensitivity label, and for that, I am using Microsoft Information Protection SDK version 1.15.86.
In the MIP SDK setup, we have to implement the IAuthDelegate to acquire a token. For this, I am following the code example found in the given link below:
IAuthDelegate implementation link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/quick-app-initialization-csharp#implement-an-authentication-delegate
When I was doing a proof of concept, I was able to add the sensitivity label in the excel using the auth-token from my web app which I injected into the AcquireToken method of the IAuthDelegate here's the code for the same
public string AcquireToken(Identity identity, string authority, string resource, string claims)
{
    var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(_authToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", _currentUser);
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new TokenCache());
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_applicationClientId, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientSecret")));

    var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential, userAssertion).Result;
    return result.AccessToken;
}

The _authToken is the hardcoded token from the web, _currentUser is the userPrincipalName (emailId) of the user.
The issue here is that the code to generate the Excel file will be called by a function app, so the above code becomes obsolete as I cannot pass hard-coded tokens.
From the above link I referenced the code and it shows a authentication prompt which I cannot show as the code will be executed by the function app.
I tried the client_credential flow, but it gave me the following exception:
The service didn’t accept the auth token. Challenge: [‘’] HttpRequest.Id={some-id}, CorrelationId=some-id, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile
Is there a way to generate the token in the IAuthDelegate without showing the prompt? Or is there any setting in Azure that we need to configure to incorporate this?
Since I was able to set the sensitivity label in my proof of concept I am assuming all the azure settings for the Mip sdk are done right as I am able to get the sensitivity label list and able to set them, but how do I get pass this scenario of the function app?
Please suggest. Thank you.

Did the toke get generated using client_credential flow?

You can also use ROPC flow which do not prompt check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc#authorization-request

@Rukmini In the RPOC one of the parameter is the password and please note that in this case I won't have  any kind of password of the user who initiated the export. I will have the emailId but not the password. Also in the above link you shared it's mentioned to avoid using RPOC as more secure options are available.
Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended

Then client_credential flow is the only option

@Rukmini Thank you for your comment
I tried the `client_credential_ flow but it's giving me an exception as mentioned in the question The service didn’t accept the auth token. Challenge: [‘’] HttpRequest.Id={some-id}, CorrelationId=some-id, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile

What are the api permissions you granted to the application

It has all the permissions required for the Mip Sdk, it does work when I tried to use the token that I get from my api app, but then I am calling the export code via queue trigger function app so I am trying to generate the token, I will try the on-behalf-of method to generate the token and see if that works for the Mip sdk but if there are other solutions I am willing to hear those too. @Rukmini

I've found a way to do it and I will post it as an answer soon @Rukmini

@BugHunterZoro - Did you get a chance to post the answer. I an keen on this solution.

@Rukmini I posed the solution that worked for me. Hope it helps.

@Samraj Posted the answer

For my case when the user triggers the excel generation from the UI, we temporarily save the OAuth token in the queue, when the queue is read, the auth token is passed and later used by the MIP SDK for a successful authentication. We went with this approach as once the message is read from the queue it's gone so there's no storage and it worked well for our usecase.
